# Can-Bus Communication - MSG-Structure (WinUser.h) Linux equivalent

Tags: c++, linux, windows, porting, can-bus

Hello StackOverflow Community

I've searched for quite a while now but I don't find a solution for my problem.
I'm working on a project right now, where I have to port a Windows tool on to a Linux operating system (Ubuntu 12.04LTS to be specific).
The Windows-based tool is written in C++ and therefore I'm trying to rewrite the Tool in C++ on Linux.
The problem I'm facing at the moment is, that in the Windows Solution there is a part where it uses 'MSG'.
Here the Code Snippet from the Windows Solution:

```
/** Callback to send CAN message */
#define CB_SEND_MSG( MSG )          CanWriteCB( MSG )
```

I already have implemented the CanWriteCB Method but I did not find a Linux equivalent to 'MSG'. I found the declaration of MSG in the Windows tool in the include file 'WinUser.h'. This looks as follows:

```
/*
 * Message structure
 */
typedef struct tagMSG {
    HWND        hwnd;
    UINT        message;
    WPARAM      wParam;
    LPARAM      lParam;
    DWORD       time;
    POINT       pt;
#ifdef _MAC
    DWORD       lPrivate;
#endif
} MSG, *PMSG, NEAR *NPMSG, FAR *LPMSG;
```

I do not know if it helps you but here is also the implementation of the 'CanWriteCB' method:

```
boolean_t CanWriteCB( Can_Msg *msg )
{
    return (CanDispatcher_SendMsgByCanBus( msg ) == CanDisp_Err_Ok ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

const Det_Config detCfg = 
{
WriteDebugErrorData
};
```

Has anybody an idea about how to achieve this structure on a Linux platform? The only thing I found was how to create a Message Queue but I don't know how this will help me at all?

Thank you for your time

Best regards
Alex

Comment: `MSG` in the posted code is not even a type name - it's a macro argument name. It might as well be `x`.

Comment: I know about that. The problem is that when I right-click on 'MSG' to check the Definition of 'MSG' I get redirected to exact that CodeSnippet I posted above in the WinUser Header file. Therefore i assume that there surely is a relationship between those two. Do I really need this macro? Isn't it way more complex than just call the CanWriteCB function instead of the macro? Or will the whole project be screwed up if I do so?

Comment: Your IDE is misleading you. You shouldn't be trying to get the definition of MSG - it's just a macro argument name. It's not a type, it doesn't have a definition.

Comment: So in the end it's just an 'error' that it's showing me the definition in the WinUser.h and it only has the same name 'by accident' and is not related at all. That's fine for the one point but doesn't answer, why my IDE (btw. Eclipse) is showing me the error message that MSG has not been declared? Maybe I'm totally  on the wrong path and just don't get the simple solution. What about the other question I asked in the comments? Would it work the same way if I just call the function where needed by itself? Or is there some kind of magic behind a macro? By the way thank you for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSG you mentioned is a macro argument, and is unrelated to `struct tagMSG` at all.

Linux has CAN support using [SocketCAN](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt) which implement socket interface for the CAN bus, and supports various HW devices. The closest thing to CAN message structure there is `struct can_frame`.